# MySQL match value from one column to another and return a value

Tags: mysql

```
Username    Employee_Name   Is_Employed L4_Username
aaa123      A1              Y           aaa131
aaa124      A2              Y           aaa131
aaa125      A3              Y           aaa131
aaa126      A4              Y           aaa131
aaa127      A5              Y           aaa131
aaa128      A6              Y           aaa131
aaa129      A7              Y           aaa131
aaa130      A8              Y           aaa130
aaa131      A9              Y           aaa130
```

what I need to do with this data is try and make a statement that can find that aaa131 (for example) and return the employee name for that L4_Username and present it AS L4_Employeename so I get the following:

```
Username    Employee_Name   Is_Employed L4_Username L4_Employeename
aaa123      A1              Y           aaa131      A9
aaa124      A2              Y           aaa131      A9
aaa125      A3              Y           aaa131      A9
aaa126      A4              Y           aaa131      A9
aaa127      A5              Y           aaa131      A9
aaa128      A6              Y           aaa131      A9
aaa129      A7              Y           aaa131      A9
aaa130      A8              Y           aaa130      A8
aaa131      A9              Y           aaa130      A8
```

It basically needs to do like an index match and return employee_name AS L4_EmployeeName

Any ideas?

Here is where i am starting

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee_Team a
    INNER JOIN Workforce_Detail b ON a.Username = b.Username
WHERE Is_Employed = 'Y'
```

Edit: Per comments I wasn't clear enough about what tables had what:

- Username is in both tables.
- L4_Username is only in Workforce_Detail
- Employee_Name is only in Workforce_Detail

Comment: `username,employee_name` & `Is_Employed L4_Username` are in two different tables? i.e `Employee_Team` and `Workforce_Detail ` ?

Comment: the first table list values  in you question  is  Employee_Team  ? and where is the table Workforce_Detail ?

Comment: i thought `L4_Employeename` comes from the first table? That what it seems like?

Comment: I don't fully understand what the end goal is. Show a table of what you want the result to be please.

Comment: do you have 2 tables? if yes, what are the columns in both tables?

Comment: @Rohlex32 i think the OP already showed what the outpput should be in the second snippet. But the confusion is about the tables used in the query

Comment: the Username is in both tables, but the L4_Username is only in Workforce Detail and the Employeename is only in workforce detail